# why am I getting an empty list when I am trying to merge two Sorted Linkedlists?

Tags: java, linked-list

The lists are sorted the way they are supposed to but when I try to merge the two lists together in my makeUnion it prints out the list is empty. can anyone help me and tell my why? in main when I try SortedLinkedList merge = sortedNames1.makeUnion(sortedNames2) I get "Empty list".

```
    public class SortedLinkedList<T extends Comparable<? super T>>
                     extends LinkedList<T> 
    {
        private LinkedList<T> list;  //the sorted list

        //the constructor
        public SortedLinkedList(LinkedList<T> in)
        {
            if(in.isEmpty())
            {
               System.out.println("Empty list");
            }
            if(in.size() < 2)
            {
               return;
            }
            else
            {  
                list = new LinkedList<T>();
                for(int i = 1; i < in.size(); i++)
                {
                    T temp = in.get(i);
                    int j = i;
                    while(j > 0 && in.get(j - 1).compareTo(temp) > 0)
                    {
                        in.set(j, in.get(j-1));
                        j--;
                    }
                    in.set(j, temp);
                }
                for(T elements : in)
                {
                    list.add(elements);  
                }
            }
        }

        //return the union of the sorted linked lists this and other
        public SortedLinkedList<T> makeUnion( SortedLinkedList<T> other)
        {
            SortedLinkedList<T> first = new SortedLinkedList<T>(other);
            SortedLinkedList<T> second = new SortedLinkedList<T>(list);
            SortedLinkedList<T> UnionList = null;

            int i = 0;
            int j = 0;
            while(i<first.size() && j<second.size())
            {
                if(first.get(i).compareTo(second.get(j)) <= 0)
                {
                    UnionList.add(first.get(i));
                    i++;
                }
                else
                {
                    UnionList.add(second.get(j));
                    j++;
                }
            }

            if(i == first.size())
            {
                    for(int k = j; k<second.size(); k++)
                    {
                        UnionList.add(second.get(k));
                    }
            }
            else if(j == second.size())
            {
                    for(int x = i; x<first.size(); x++)
                    {
                        UnionList.add(first.get(x));
                    }
            }    

            return UnionList;      
        }


        //print the items int list
        public void print()
        {
            ListIterator itr = list.listIterator();
            while(itr.hasNext())
            {
                System.out.println(itr.next());
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
        SortedLinkedList<T> UnionList = null;
```

You can't call `UnionList.add()` if `UnionList` is `null`. You will need to allocate a new list before you can add things to it.

Actually, I think your original problem might be that `SortedLinkedList` both *extends* `LinkedList` and also contains an *instance* of a `LinkedList`. You should choose one or the other, but not both. Your code sometimes accesses one list, and sometimes the other, so one list appears empty because you've added items to the *other* list.

Comment: thanks for the help it works :). you where right the original problem was with my sortedlinkedlist and unionlist. I fixed it and it works now.

Answer (score 0):

You don't initialize UnionList before you start using it.

```
SortedLinkedList<T> UnionList = null;
```

should read

```
SortedLinkedList<T> UnionList = new SortedLinkedList<T>();
```

As a bonus, ListIterator ought to be ListIterator<T> so that the right toString() method is used.  As it is, you'll be calling Object.toString().

Comment: SortedLinkedList<T> UnionList = new SortedLinkedList<T>();

Comment: I tried that but it tells me cannot be applied to given types required LinkList<T>

Answer (score 0):

Because you used inheritance instead of delegation. You inherit LinkedList, and the only thing you do is define a constructor which adds the content of an unsorted list to a new one, in the appropriate order. But you don't override the `size` method, so this method is inherited from LinkedList, which doesn't care about your internal sorted list and thus always returns 0.

Extending a collection is, most of the time, a bad idea. In this case, it's a particularly bad idea because it's impossible to have a sorted LinkedList that respects the LinkedList API. Suppose your list contains A, B and C, and you call `addFirst("Z")` on it. Where will you put Z, if at the beginning, your list is not sorted anymore. If at the end, you don't respect the contract of `addFirst`.

Just *use* linked lists (instead of extending them), and sort them. You could just do :

```
LinkedList list = new LinkedList(someUnsortedList);
Collections.sort(list); // now the list is sorted
list.addAll(someOtherList);
Collections.sort(list); // now both lists are merged, and the resulting list is sorted.
```

Comment: we have to write our own method and not use the Collections.sort

Comment: Then just use MyOwnUtilityClass.sort(list) instead of Collections.sort(list) (and, why not, MyOwnUtilityClass.mergeSortedLists(list1, list2))